# Как сделать чтобы при неправильном вводе логина и пароля писало "Неверный логин или пароль"?

Tags: python, windows, smtp, gmail, smtplib

Это python
Вот код:

```
import smtplib


def check():
    user = input("Login: ")
    password = input("Password: ")
    url = "smtp.gmail.com" 


    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(url, 465)
    server.login(user, password)





def main():
    check()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import smtplib


def check():
    user = input("Login: ")
    password = input("Password: ")
    url = "smtp.gmail.com" 


    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(url, 465)
    try:
        server.login(user, password)
    except:
        print("Неверный логин или пароль")





def main():
    check()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```